Mapster - can type mapping be validated?
For the following classes
public class Source
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

I'd expect configuration validation to fail, but we only observe an exception then executing the actual mapping
    [Fact]
    public void Should_Validate_Type_Mapping()
    {
        var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();

        config.ForType<Source, Destination>()
            .Map(dest => dest.Number, source => source.Time);

        // Does not throw
        config.Compile();

        var source = new Source
        {
            Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
        };

        // Actually throws System.InvalidCastException : Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'.
        var result = source.Adapt<Destination>(config);
    }

Is there some kind of configuration switch, that would allow us to validate mapped types? We've switched from Automapper and would like to catch invalid mappings without writing tests for all of them.
